# Google Drive - Trash/Bin Won't Empty with 200,000 files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Google Drive has told me I have 200,000 files in my trash/bin, taking up 19GB. I've repeatedly tried clicking the "Empty Bin" option in browser, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I called Google Drive Support, and the guy said that when you click Empty Bin, it only gets rid of what your browser has loaded... He recommended scrolling and then clicking empty bin occasionally. What kind of a suggestion is that? I said I have 200,000 files in my bin, which he already knew, and apologised, saying it was the only way.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue with my google driver. It is very frustrating. I decided to switch to dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

I'm experiencing the very same thing right now:

- I accidentally synced a huge folder containing > 300GB worth of stuff,
  so I quickly reached the 15GB limit without realising the issue
- I moved this folder to the bin, clicked empty bin, but it struggles to
  load, and when it does it loads and displays more folders, suggesting
  that emptying bin contents only deletes what is displayed in the bin

However...

*I believe it is deleting the bin contents, just very slowly*

The 'Storage' level at the bottom of the left panel goes down by 0.1GB every few minutes. I believe it's iterating through every bin item and removing it permanently, hence why it's taking so long.

Hope that info helps someone else too!

Comment: Still the case today. Trash with a lot of files will require some... patience. ;) So Emptying the trash and comming back a few minutes later to see if it is working is the way to go. For me, it is processing with the Chrome window closed.